# Crystal Formatting having 2 Subgroups?

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, crystal-reports

I am struggling with organizing my data via crystal reports.

I am attempting to essentially do a group by for 2 different things on the same level.

I am currently unaware on how to make it so that each group is not a level below the previous group.

What I am trying to do is group by a name, and then have 2 seperate fields like actions, and planning to be organized independently from eachother below it.

heres essentially how its organized:

```
Main Group
  Name
    (planning, and actions)
```

the problem is we get repeats, if i have one planning and 2 actions, the one planning will get repeated for every action. and the actual planning and actions are not grouped together themselves.

rather than doing it like that, id prefer to do

```
Main Group
   Name
      Planning
      Actions
```

I was wondering if anyone new how i'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something like this using subreports.  Create the Group Header in your main report, then use a subreport to display the Details and Group Footer, and paste the subreport into the Detail section of the main report.

Comment: that is perfect, I am still working on formatting everything but I managed to group the data in the proper order. Thank you so much!